# There a way to have primary key ids without any gaps

Tags: sql, database, oracle, primary-key, sequential

I'm creating an application with Java Spring and Oracle DB.

In the app, I want to generate a primary key value that is unique as well as ordered and without gaps: `1,2,3,4,5` instead of `1,2,5,7,8,9`.

I've at one point used `max(id) + 1` to get the maximum value of the id, and the id of the next/current transaction. However I know it isn't perfect in the case of concurrency with multiple users or multiple sessions.

I've tried using sequences, but even with the `ORDER` tag it could still create gaps with the possibility of a failed transaction.

```
REATE SEQUENCE num_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
ORDER NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```

I need there to be gapless values as a requirement, however I'm unsure how it's possible in the case of multiple users/multiple sessions.

Comment: What happens if you delete a row? Do you have to renumber all the rows that follow so the values have no gaps? What if you insert a row but have to rollback, but other rows have been inserted in the meantime?

Comment: The application is implementing a soft delete, so no records should be deleted from the database.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do it.

The goal of primary keys is not to be displayed on the UI or to be exposed to the external world, but only to provide a *unique identifier* of the row.

In simple words, a primary key doesn't need to be sexy or good looking. It's an internal identifier.

If you are considering the idea of having *serial identifier*, that means you probably want to display it somewhere or you want to expose it to the external world. If that's the case, then create a secondary column (also unique) that serves this "public relations" goal. It can be automatically generated, or updated at leisure without affecting the integrity of the database.

It can also be generated by a secondary process that runs in a deferred way (e.g. every 10 minutes) that finds all the "unassigned" new rows, and gives them the new number. This has the advantage that is not vulnerable to concurrency.

Comment: yeah, that's the case. Are there specific ways to do this in Oracle? I'm still somewhat new to RDMS.

Comment: @WattMonki You can use the Oracle Scheduler to run jobs periodically, or you can run an external cron job. You can also create a queue that receives all new rows and a consumer process that reads from the queue and assigns the new number. All of those are good candidates, so you should choose according to what you are more familiar with.

Comment: As pointed out, a 'gapless' PK is a fool's errand.  Even if you try to achieve some 'gapless' attribute in a non-PK column, the same issues of maintenance still apply.  Other than "it's the requirement"  what is the real intended use of this data element, and what is the _business_ reason for it being gapless? (many "requirements" are without merit, and it's our job as analysts to identify and push back on them)